# Why is Python quick pow prone to timeout? Is there any way to optimize Python code in algorithm competitions?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, optimization

The reason is that during the operation of a problem, and it will be wrong to use long long (and cannot use __int128), so Python was used instead. The time complexity of the algorithm is definitely right, but using Python has always been tle (I've also encountered it before).

I have roughly checked and found that Python's quick pow is too slow. Always getting stuck inexplicably, here is my Python code:

```
def qpow(a, b, m):
    ans = 1
    tmp = a
    while b:
        if b & 1:
            ans = ans * tmp % m;
        tmp = tmp * tmp % m
        b >>= 1
    return ans
```

A is the base number, b is the exponent, and m is the modulus. Perhaps Python modulo operations are too slow?

The following is the problem and complete code:
problem:https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/17/D
By using the extended Euler theorem to optimize the exponent, the exponent is less than or equal to 2E9. At the same time, b directly takes the modulus of c, and b is also less than 1E9. Finally, running a fast power is enough. Although using c++to directly take the modulus of b while processing n is definitely possible, it is very convenient to use Python to solve the problem.

this is code:

```
from math import *

def phi(a):
    ans = 1
    up = int(sqrt(a))
    for i in range(2, up + 1):
        if a % i == 0:
            a //= i
            ans *= (i - 1)

            while a % i == 0:
                a //= i
                ans *= i
    if a > 1:
        ans *= (a - 1)
    return ans

def qpow(a, b, m):
    ans = 1
    tmp = a
    while b:
        if b & 1:
            ans = ans * tmp % m;
        tmp = tmp * tmp % m
        b >>= 1
    return ans


def exphi(a, b, m):
    p = phi(m)

    while b > p and b != b % p + p:
        b = b %p + p
    return qpow(a, b, m)

b, n, c = map(int, input().split(" "))
re = exphi(b, n - 1, c)
re = (b - 1) * re % c

if  re == 0:
    re = c
print(re)
```

use > 2000ms, tle(use python's pow() too)

and c++'s code（having something difference, but O is similar）：

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
#define int long long
int phi(int a)
{
    int ans = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= a; i ++)
    {
        if (a % i == 0)
        {
            a /= i;
            ans *= (i - 1);
            while (a % i == 0)  a /= i, ans *= i;
        }
    }

    if (a > 1)
        ans *= (a - 1);
    return ans;
}

int qpow(int a, int b, int m)
{
    int ans = 1;
    int tmp = a;
    while (b)
    {
        if (b & 1)
            ans = ans * tmp % m;
        tmp = tmp * tmp % m;
        b >>= 1;
    }
    return ans;
}

// a^b = a ^ (b % phi(m) + phi(m)) (mod m)

signed main()
{
    string b, n;
    long long nc;
    cin >> b >> n >> nc;

    int nb = 0, nn = 0;

    for (auto i : b)
        nb = (nb * 10 + (i - '0')) % nc;

    int p = phi(nc);
    int flag = 0;
    for (auto i : n)
    {
            nn = (nn * 10 + (i - '0'));
            if (nn >= p)
                flag = true;
            nn %= p;
    }
 
    if (flag) nn += p;
    int re = qpow(nb, nn - 1, nc);

    re = (nb - 1 + nc) % nc * re % nc;
    if (!re)
        re = nc;
    cout << re << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

use 63 ms, accept

Comment: First, Python already has [a faster version of this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) built-in. Second, it sounds like your real problem is likely an algorithmic issue, and I don't mean in the algorithm you've shown us - I mean in the code that calls this function.

Comment: thank you, but my algorithm is no problem, because i use c++ can ac.And python's fuction can't multiply while taking modulus.this is problem:https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/17/D      i want to use Extended Euler's theorem and quick pow to solve it

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Specifically, state with which argument values it is slow an what exactly you consider to be "slow".

Comment: the example is in the link. i use python to submit that it will get tle, and  the time complexity of the algorithm is definitely right. I have already mentioned in the question what I believe is the problem of quick pow modules(qpow), and it is related to modulus

Comment: You really ought to take another look at the `pow` docs, because your `qpow` is just a slower reimplementation of 3-argument `pow`.

Comment: Anyway, if you're doing *trial division* here, that's almost certainly going to take way longer than the modular exponentiation.

Comment: OK, thanks, I have already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factoring `M` to compute `phi(n)` takes `O(M^(1/2))` time in the worst case. Modular exponentiation by squaring takes `O(log M)` steps involving addition, multiplication, and modular reduction. Even considering that these involve large numbers with non-constant time operations, its still massively faster to just do the extra multiplications rather than compute the multiplicative order to reduce the number of multiplications.

Its better to just use the builtin [pow()](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/17/D) function, which can be passed a modulus, and will perform proper modular exponentiation by squaring. Straight from the docs:

```py
>>> pow(38, -1, mod=97)
23

>>> 23 * 38 % 97 == 1
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Python quick **pow()** can be slow for large numbers because it uses a naive algorithm involving repeated multiplication operations. This can lead to a high computational cost and a long execution time, especially when working with large numbers.

If you want to optimize then go with ***Modular Exponentiation*** algorithm. For more details learn from the [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Modular_Exponentiation).

Comment: Both the question's `qpow` and Python's built-in `pow` already do modular exponentiation.